# Flutter - Unable to navigate away/show dialog when snapshot error occurs

Tags: flutter, dart

I got this simple build function which should show a dialog when the `snapshot` has an error, but I'm unable to do so without getting the following error:

> flutter: The following assertion was thrown building
>   FutureBuilder(dirty, dependencies: flutter:
>   [_LocalizationsScope-[GlobalKey#f4f3f], _InheritedTheme], state:
>   flutter: _FutureBuilderState#175f8): flutter:
>   setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build. flutter: This
>   Overlay widget cannot be marked as needing to build because the
>   framework is already in the flutter: process of building widgets.  A
>   widget can be marked as needing to be built during the build phase
>   flutter: only if one of its ancestors is currently building. This
>   exception is allowed because the framework flutter: builds parent
>   widgets before children, which means a dirty descendant will always be
>   built. flutter: Otherwise, the framework might not visit this widget
>   during this build phase. flutter: The widget on which setState() or
>   markNeedsBuild() was called was: flutter:
>   Overlay-[LabeledGlobalKey#07fd4]

Code:

```
showUnknownErrorAlertDialog(BuildContext context, [void Function() onClose]) {

  showDialog(
    context: context,
    builder: (BuildContext builderContext) {

      return AlertDialog(
        title: Text(AppLocalizations.of(builderContext).lang['unknownError']),
        actions: <Widget>[

          FlatButton(
            child: Text(AppLocalizations.of(builderContext).lang['close']),
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.of(builderContext).pop();

              if (onClose != null) {
                onClose();
              }
            },
          ),
        ],
      );
    }
  );
}

goBack() {
  locator<AppNavigation>().navigateTo('gameOverview', AppGameArgs(gameName));
}

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder(
      future: getGameSession(),
      builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<DocumentSnapshot> snapshot) {

        if (snapshot.hasError) {

          return showUnknownErrorAlertDialog(context, () {
            goBack();
          });
        }
        / ... omitted code .../
```

How am I supposed to handle errors in the build function if I'm not allowed to show a dialog or navigate away instantly when there's an error?

Answer (score 0):

you can't return the `dialog` directly from the `FuturBuilder`.You have to use `showDialog()` to show any dialog and for the click event if you are using navigation in the dialog it'll be used as the navigation of the dialog not the page.

```
if(snapshot.hasError()){
  showDialog(showUnknownErrorAlertDialog(context, () {
            Navigator.of(context).pop(1);
          })).then((value){
        if(value=null && value==1)
            goBack();
   });
   return Container();
}
```

you can return value from dialog and check the result and run your goBack() there